# How to direct to a new page when a button is clicked using ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am working in React.I have created a button ,which on click should lead the user to the newpage.I made a component About and imported it as well.
I created a function routeChange which would direct to a new page on Clicking the button.But when the button is clicked I am not being directed to any page .

Instead I get an error.

Probably there is not any error with folders.

I imported my About Component as:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Navbar,NavbarBrand, Jumbotron, Button} from 'reactstrap';
import './App.css';
import Description from './Description';
import './description.css';
import {useHistory,withRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import About from './About';

function App() {
  const history=useHistory();
 routeChange = () =>{
   this.history.push('/About');
   }
return (
<withRouter>
<Navbar color="dark">
  <div className="container">
  <NavbarBrand className="navbar-brand abs" href="/">
      Cheat Sheet
  </NavbarBrand>
  </div>
</Navbar>
<Jumbotron>
  <p className="lead">Quick Review ,Revision And Mnemonic Are Always Good</p>
  <hr my-2/>
  <p className="lead">Page is still under Construction</p>
  <Button onClick={routeChange} className="About"color="primary">About Us</Button>
</Jumbotron>

    <div className="img-thumbnail">
       <Description/>
    </div>

  <div className="footer">
    &copy;Abhilekh Gautam all right reserved.
    <p>Follow<a rel="noopener noreferrer"href="https://www.quora.com/profile/Abhilekh-Gautam-1" target="_blank">Abhilekh Gautam</a> On quora</p>
  </div>
  
</withRouter>
)
}
```

export default App;

Comment: you have a typo when closing `Jumbotron`, it's closed with lower case `jumbotron` and the `Router` is not matching a closing tag

Comment: NO No i just made code available upto the button element

Comment: please provide the code as it's on your machine to avoid confusion

Comment: your `btnclick` function makes no sense. It can't return an element and your function is actually returning a function that returns an element wrapped in an object.

Comment: what is the effect you are trying to achieve??

Comment: Where do you expect the value to be returned **to**?

Comment: I want a new page to be called when the button is clicked

Comment: If you want a new page, then use a link. You can't just return something to an event handler trigger.

Comment: is Button styled component??you need to make it Link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a couple issues here.

1. change `function App (){}` to `const App = () => {}` its going to help with your binding later because arrow functions are interpreted differently from declarative functions
2. this function needs some help

```
routeChange = () =>{
   this.history.push('/About');
   }
```

first of all you have to declare the function as a constant because App is a functional component not a class component.

second of all because App is a functional component you don't need the this keyword because routeChange is an arrow function and is bound to App

your final function should look like this:

```
const routeChange = () => {
   history.push('/About');
   }
```

3. make your button onClick handler an anonymous function so it is called on click only and not on render

```
<Button onClick={routeChange}/>
```

this code makes the route change function get called when the button renders. Instead change it to

```
<Button onClick={() => routeChange()}
```

4. make sure /About is a route to another component in your router or else you will get a 404 error or hit your no match component (if you have one)

---

your final product should look something like this

in app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Navbar,NavbarBrand, Jumbotron, Button} from 'reactstrap';
import './App.css';
import Description from './Description';
import './description.css';
import {useHistory,withRouter, BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import About from './About';

function App() {
return (
<>
<Navbar color="dark">
  <div className="container">
  <NavbarBrand className="navbar-brand abs" href="/">
      Cheat Sheet
  </NavbarBrand>
  </div>
</Navbar>
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
    <Route exact path='/About' component={About}
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
</>
)
}
```

then your home component would look like this:

```
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'

const Home = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const routeChange = () => {
   history.push('/About');
   }
return (
<>
<Jumbotron>
  <p className="lead">Quick Review ,Revision And Mnemonic Are Always Good</p>
  <hr my-2/>
  <p className="lead">Page is still under Construction</p>
  <Button onClick={() => routeChange()} className="About"color="primary">About Us</Button>
</Jumbotron>

    <div className="img-thumbnail">
       <Description/>
    </div>

  <div className="footer">
    &copy;Abhilekh Gautam all right reserved.
    <p>Follow<a rel="noopener noreferrer"href="https://www.quora.com/profile/Abhilekh-Gautam-1" target="_blank">Abhilekh Gautam</a> On quora</p>
  </div> 
</>
)
}

export default Home
```

Comment: In the terminal of vs code it says :About is defined but not used.How ever i have imported it

Comment: You have imported it in your App file but you have not created a route that goes to  '/About'. importing it in your file means that you could add the JSX
<About /> component in that file

Comment: yeah. Should i import it somewhere else?

Comment: you need to set up a router

Comment: I am totally new to React,Can U help me? I've an error of Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: Why am I getting routeChange is not defined in Home.js?

Comment: sorry we need to move the function definition into the home.js component

Comment: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression,I have this error now

Comment: I re-edited the answer above. make sure the routeChange function declaration has const before it. and that the button components onClick looks like this onClick={()=> routeChange()}

Comment: Yeah,i changed it as well.I still have the error -Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Comment: the home component needs a return statement